# What is the difference between GraphQLJSON and GraphQLJSONObject exported by graphql-type-json?

Tags: json, graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql, graphql-tools

From the official package documentation:

> GraphQLJSON can represent any JSON-serializable value, including
> scalars, arrays, and objects. GraphQLJSONObject represents
> specifically JSON objects, which covers many practical use cases for
> JSON scalars.

It sounds a bit confusing as to me both definitions seem quite similar. Can someone please help me understand this better with an example? Thanks in anticipation.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-type-json

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSON value can be of type string, number, boolean, object, array or null. So `GraphQLJSON` represents any of this, while `GraphQLJSONObject` represents JSON objects exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

The wording can be confusing. There is a discussion [here](https://github.com/taion/graphql-type-json/issues/133) but I think a couple examples make it easier to understand.

`GraphQLJSON` will accept anything that you could assign as the value side of a key value pair in valid JSON.

```js
// Each line represents valid GraphQLJSON
3
"3"
"foo"
{"foo": 3}
{"foo": ["bar", "3"]}

// Invalid GraphQLJSON might be something like this
foo
```

And `GraphQLJSONObject` is more strict. It only includes the `object` subset of values contained in `GraphQLJSON` (so no raw strings, numbers, etc.)

```js
// Each line represents valid GraphQLJSONObject
{"foo": 3}
{"foo": ["bar", "3"]}

// Each line represents invalid GraphQLJSONObject
3
"3"
"foo"
```